# Always shows that the username is taken

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When checking if a username is taken in the DB, the code always shows the message that the username is taken. If I change the condition in ajax the message changes, but it shows always same even if user is in the DB

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#email").keyup(provjeraEmaila);

  $("#korime").blur(function() {


    if ($("#korime").val().length >= 5) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "korisnici.php",
        data: {
          fieldName: "korisnicko_ime",
          filedVal: $("#korime").val()
        },
        success: [function(data) {
          if (data == 0) {
            $("#username-span").html("username is taken!");
            $("#username-span").attr('class', 'username-span');
          } else {
            $("#username-span").html("username is free!");
            $("#username-span").attr('class', 'username-span');
          }
        }]
      });
      $("#username-span").html("");

    }
  });

});
```

This is the PHP code:

```php
<?php
include_once 'baza.class.php';
if (isset($_POST['registracija']))
{
    $veza = new Baza();
    $veza->spojiDB();

    $korime = $_POST['korime'];

    $upit = "SELECT korisnicko_ime FROM korisnik WHERE 
korisnicko_ime='$korime'";
    $rezultat = $veza->selectDB($upit);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($rezultat) > 0)
    {
        echo 0;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: step one would be to console.log that `data` to find out what's in it. Also, try not to use `==` in Javascript, use `===` instead unless you *know* it is essential to force implicit type conversions just to make a boolean check possible (which is virtually never). `data == 0` will be true if data is 0, or `false`, or an empty string, or any object with a custom `valueOf()` function, etc.

Comment: what have you tried to resolve the issue? You can add console logs or debugger statements in your success function to inspect the data and see why its behaving that way.

Comment: on a security note, that `$upit` variable looks incredibly suspiscious, why would a _user_ be able to tell your server which database to use? That should be fixed information on your server, not something a client can trivially "hack" by changing the POST value.

Comment: You set `fieldName: "korisnicko_ime"` in your ajax POST request but you're looking for `$_POST["korime"]` in your PHP. If there is a null in the database's `korisnik`  field then the username exists.